# solving $\int x^7\sqrt{3+2x^4}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I'm trying to solve $\int x^7\sqrt{3+2x^4}dx$

All I have so far is

Let $u$ = $3+2x^4$

$du$ = $8x^3$ $dx$

$\frac{du}{8x^3}$ = $dx$

Therefore,

$\int x^7\sqrt{u}$ $\frac{du}{8x^3}$

$\frac{1}{8}$$\int x^4\sqrt{u}$ ${du}$

Since there is still a $x$ variable in the integral, I'm not sure where to go from here. Any ideas?

Comment: You almost did it... write $x^4$ as $(u-3)/2$ in your last expression, you will get a primitive expressed by means of $u$, replace $u$ by $3+2x^4$ and you're done !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try $u=x^4\to du=4x^3 dx$ instead, and note that $4x^7dx = udu$.
Then:
$$\int x^7\sqrt{3+2x^4}dx = \frac{1}{4}\int u\sqrt{3+2u}du$$
Now, it's easier to take $v=3+2u, dv=2du$ to get:
$$\frac{1}{16}\int (v-3)\sqrt{v}dv$$
Which you can probably solve.

Answer (score 1):

Using your substitution, we have $\displaystyle x=\left(\frac{u-3}{2}\right)^{1/4}$. Substitute this formula for $x$ into your new integral and solve!

Answer (score 1):

Given $\int x^7 \sqrt{3+2x^4} dx$. Assume that $3+2x^4= u$ then $8x^3 dx=du$. Hence the givenm integral becomes $\int \sqrt{u}\frac{u-3}{2}\frac{du}{8}$ which is \begin{align*}
 &\int \sqrt{u}\frac{u-3}{2}\frac{du}{8}\\
=&\frac{1}{16}\int (u^{3/2}-3u^{1/2})du\\
=&\frac{1}{16}(\frac{u^{5/2}}{5/2}-3\frac{u^{3/2}}{3/2})+c\\
=&\frac{1}{16}(\frac{2}{5}(3+2x^4)^{5/2}-2(3+2x^4)^{3/2})+c
\end{align*}
where $c$ is constant of integration.

Comment: That's the general idea. You unfortunately made many mistakes in your calculation, and the final result is wrong.

Comment: @ V.Rossetto I would be happy to know my mistakes so that in future it won't happen again. Would you please let me know what are they ?

Comment: You've corrected most of your mistakes in your last edit. It remains only one in the exponent $5/4$ in the final result: it should be $5/2$.

Comment: @V.Rossetto Opps !!! That was really indeed a mistake. Thank you so much for alerting me. I have done the editing. And also I apologise for such typing mistake.